# Execute script after razor syntax is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have some razor syntax which is dynamically generating an html table and populating with data while generating it. I needed to make a jQuery ajax call to my MVC ASP.Net controller to get some data to go in another field in this exact table. Now what I was trying to do is to iterate through the child nodes of this table and append this field cell by cell in these rows after it loads.

However this is not being successful, the table is showing as if it doesn't have any child nodes i.e. the razor syntax is not done executing by that time.

What can I do so that this script for adding the extra field is executed after the html table has been filled up with data? This is the code I have. This is the razor and html syntax.

```
@if (Model.ToList().Count > 0) {
      <table id ="groupTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Group Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="innerTable">
        @foreach (var group in Model) {
        // display a link with each GroupName as a list which directs to that group with that id
        <tr>    
            <td> @Html.ActionLink(group.Group.GroupName,"DisplayGroup","Groups", new {id = group.GroupId},null) </td>

            <td>
                @if(group.Group.Description.Length > 40){   
                    @group.Group.Description.Substring(0, 40)                   
                    <span>...</span> 
                }
                else
                {
                    @group.Group.Description.Substring(0, group.Group.Description.Length - 1)
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
     </tbody>
  </table>
}
```

And this is the script executed on document.ready

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  @foreach (var group in Model)
    {
    <text>
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Groups/GetInvitedFriends',
        data: { groupId: '@group.Group.GroupId' },
        success: function (friendMembers) {
            $.each(friendMembers, function (index, friendName) {
                // append friend Members at row with index index at that cell
                var tbody = $('#innerTable')[0];
                var trow = tbody.childNodes[index];

                if (trow.index() === 0) {
                    trow.append('<td> Members </td>');
                } else {
                    trow.append('<td>' + friendName + '</td>');
                }
            });
        },
        traditional: true
        });
    </text>
    }
})
```

Comment: I would be very wary of this approach as its ability to scale is extremely limited. Given a list of 100 groups, then 100 request back to the web server to populate this data.  Not only will be browser potentially become unresponsive during these calls, but the browser will only open so many connections at once to a single domain (4 maybe??).  As well, IIS does have a request limit and given enough users requesting this page, you could find yourself blocking additional requests. I would ask why you could not include the requested members (friends) in your initial view model to the razor view.

Comment: You are right Tommy! I guess I could have passed to the razor view by saving the members in the database and requesting them from there

Comment: Can you add the Action method "GetInvitedFriends". Is you Json object(friendMembers) constructed properly?

Comment: I solved this by returning an html string from GetInvitedFriends and using the @Html.RenderAction directly in the html!

Answer (score 0):

As the javascript will only be executed on the client browser, you can store the group's id in an javascript array and then in document load, loop on this array to add each of your extra cells.

This is the javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //List of groups id
    var groupIds = [];

    $(function() {

        //Initializing the array with values
        @foreach (var group in Model) {
            <text>groupIds .push(@group.Group.GroupId);</text>
         }

        InsertExtraCells(groupIds.pop()); //Insert for the first groupid in the array

    });

    function InsertExtraCells(groupId) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Groups/GetInvitedFriends',
            data: { groupId: '@group.Group.GroupId' },
            success: function (friendMembers) {

                //Do your work

                $.each(friendMembers, function (index, friendName) {
                    // append friend Members at row with index index at that cell
                    var tbody = $('#innerTable')[0];
                    var trow = tbody.childNodes[index];

                    if (trow.index() === 0) {
                        trow.append('<td> Members </td>');
                    } else {
                        trow.append('<td>' + friendName + '</td>');
                    }
                });


                //If ids remaining in the array, loop to the next group id
                if (groupIds.length > 0) {
                    InsertExtraCells(groupIds.pop());
                }
                else {
                    //Do whatever when finish
                }
            },
            traditional: true
        });

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @hemma731. Still the same problem though! The html table has no nodes by the time the script is executed

Comment: If you want the extra cells to be added before displaying in web browser, you can use **Html.RenderAction method**. The method will call the GetInvitedFriends action from your Groups controller and write the result at the right place. Am i clear ?

Comment: so this method is razor syntax and if I use it it will render the html correctly. I'll try some things :) Thanks!